# How I can align 2 equations with LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I'm writing an article and I would like to write two equations which will be align with the egal sign.

My script :

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{center}
$
X = ( \alpha_i - \alpha_0 ) * cos (\delta_0) \\
Y = \delta_i - \delta_0\qedhere$

\end{center}
\end{eqnarray}
```

But I get an error. I tried lots of things but impossible to get a correct shape. 
Could you help me and say me where I have a mistake ?

Thank you !

Comment: If yes try this: `\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
X &= ( \alpha_i - \alpha_0 ) * cos (\delta_0) \\
Y & = \delta_i - \delta_0\qedhere
\end{align*}

\end{document}`

Comment: @Aneconomist Your answer doesn't work, I get this error `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ...Y & = \delta _i - \delta _0\qedhere \end{align}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to create two equations that have equal signs aligned. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The `amsmath` and `amsthm` packages will allow you to do so. Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
X &= ( \alpha_i - \alpha_0 ) * cos (\delta_0) \\
Y & = \delta_i - \delta_0\qedhere
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

Comment: It's strange because the package is loaded, but it doesn't seem work .. Did you see my error ?

Comment: @Andromedae93 I forgot to include `asthma` package, sorry. After edit the code should work.